# Creating JMS queue dynamically using JMX

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, wildfly, jmx

I am using Wildfly 10 AS and want to use a separate JMS queue for each client (bidirectional server-client communucation that is targeted to the specific client only). This is following the P2P scenario described here: http://www.straub.as/java/jms/basic.html

On Wildfly 10, I am using activeMQ, and I want to create the queues (and everything else, if there's something more I need) automatically by the app. The administrative tasks such as adding a new client (and so a new queue) should be automated by UI operations.

I already found this solution to create the queue automatically over JMX:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JMX+subsystem+configuration
which I was able to adopt to Wildfly10 I think (***consider***: I had to change the JMX ObjectName used to address the activemq MBean, and had add more parameters to addQueue operation - am I using the wrong addQueue operation now?)

It seems I am using a wrong "addQueue" method (i.e. on a wrong JMX object), or I am missing something else... I can create a queue now. The queue appears in JMX Console. But when I try to send, i get an error. Am I missing something to create a JMS endpoint, in addition to the queue?

> Error when using the Queue:
>
> ```
> Got ConnectionFactory jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms/queue/MyNewQueue -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.jms.queue.MyNewQueue
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
>     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:184)
>     at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:127)
> ```

My code to create the Queue (which is executed without error):

```
    String host = "localhost";
    int port = 10990;  // management-web port
    String urlString =
        System.getProperty("jmx.service.url","service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://" + host + ":" + port);

    JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(urlString);
    JMXConnector jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, null);
    MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();


    String operationName="addQueue";
    String name="MyNewQueue2";
    boolean durable=true;
    String filter="MyNewQueue";
    String address="jms/queue/MyNewQueue";
    ObjectName activeMQ = new ObjectName("jboss.as:subsystem=messaging-activemq,server=default");//org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=default,Type=Broker");
        Object[] params = {name,durable, filter, address};
        String[] sig = {"java.lang.String", "java.lang.boolean", "java.lang.String","java.lang.String",};
        conn.invoke(activeMQ, operationName, params, sig);
```

My code to access the queue, which fails (based on http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/how-to-code-a-remote-jms-client-for-wildfly-8):

```
private String MESSAGE = "Hello, World!";
private String CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
private String DESTINATION = "jms/queue/MyNewQueue";//but works with default "jms/queue/exampleQueue";

[...] 
Context namingContext = null;
JMSContext context = null;


// Set up the namingContext for the JNDI lookup
final Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
      "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "$local");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "$local");
namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext
        .lookup(CONNECTION_FACTORY);
System.out.println("Got ConnectionFactory " + ONNECTION_FACTORY);

Destination destination = (Destination) namingContext
        .lookup(DESTINATION);
System.out.println("Got JMS Endpoint " + DESTINATION);

context = connectionFactory.createContext("internal", "internal");
context.createProducer().send(destination, MESSAGE);
```

Comment: If you look in the admin webpage, do you see the JMS queue you just created (which would confirm that it was properly created)?

Comment: no, it is not listed as an endpoint.

See WildFly config web page screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/fGHnkQG.png
But I see it in JMX console: https://i.imgur.com/n5X4PkD.png

Comment: Why do you need a unique queue per client? You would normally create a queue and then use a selector that each client would then use to filter so it only gets the messages destined for that client

Comment: With one single queue and message selectors it works. But shouldn't that be seen as workaround, because different queues would allow a finer permission configuration? In this case, with one common queue I't need to handle data protection myself, and not only over TLS, because I can't trust that noone else is accessing the queue, with a client that is open to receive all messages without filtering - or am I wrong here?